Expo ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync() crashes after native build. Works on Expo Go
After building native app for ios using eas build, app crashes upon trying to request camera permissions with ImagePicker.
Expo SDK 50
"expo-image-picker": "14.7.1"
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";

const takePhoto = async () => {

        let cameraStatus = await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync(); // WORKS IN EXPO GO, BREAKS ONCE ON IOS

        if (cameraStatus.granted === false) {
            Alert.alert(
                "Camera Access",
                `You must allow camera access in order to take a photo.`,
                [{ text: "OK", onPress: () => Linking.openSettings() }]
            );
            return;
        }

        const camera = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
            allowsEditing: false,
            aspect: [4, 3],
            quality: 0.1,
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images
        });

        if (!camera.canceled) {
            await addImages(camera.assets);
            setUploadVisible(true);
        }
    };

Asking for permission and using the media library works fine.
let libraryStatus = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();

app.json includes all necessary fields
"plugins": [
      [
        "expo-image-picker",
        {
          "photosPermission": "This app accesses your photos to share documents with ...",
          "cameraPermission": "This app accesses your camera to share documents with ...",
          "microphonePermission": false
        }
      ]
    ],
    "ios": {
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "This app accesses your camera to share documents with ...",
        "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "This app accesses your photos to share documents with ..."
      }
    },

Crash report in xcode

